# Why Android Studio uses let instead of run when creating Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

Android Studio creates this code when you create a `Fragment` using File -> New -> Fragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}
```

Isn't it better to use `run` on `arguments` since you can omit `it`? I know you use `let` for null-safety but `run` also gives you `Bundle`, not `Bundle?`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.run {
        param1 = getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        param2 = getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }
}
```

Is there a particular reason why it uses `let` instead of `run`?

Comment: I don't know if this is a reason, but the version with `run` could potentially be confusing if you'd want to call the method `getString(int)` from the fragment itself. With `let` you have the `it` variable to help out understanding that the method being called belongs to the `Bundle` class.

Comment: No reason, they just like `it`. They aren't as fun in code review though. I'd name it `.let { args ->`

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, neither of these really make sense, since they both return a value.

Since you don't want to return a value in this case:

- If you want to use `it`, use [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) instead of `let`.
- If you want to use the receiver, use [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) instead of `run`.

And...no, I don't know why Android Studio would use `let` instead of `run`.

Comment: they also return a value

Comment: Alright, technically yes, what I meant is the last value of the *lambda* isn't used. Like you use `let` or `run` if you want to do some operation and then "return" the last value of the block.

Answer (score 0):

You saw those 'it' on let mate? This is the only thing that these two are different about. But, because of that, they have different uses. First of, on run, calling 'this' will point out to the object that called run. thus, primarily, all properties or methods that the object has will be called. As an example:

```
...
mObject?.run {
    hello();
}
...
```

This will call the hello method of the object. But, lets say its the same scenario but you want to call a function with the same name as the method of the object. As an example:

```
...
fun hello() = print("not the hello from that object")
...
mObject?.run {
    hello();
}
...
```

This will still work, but, you will still run the hello from the object. Which to as, when you use let, you could choose wether to use the method the object has or the function.

***P.S. run can run along on its own while let needs to be accessed from a variable etc.***

## Bonus

There are two more to this option which are apply and also. Now, what differs these two from let and run? let and run can return themselves or anything else, or fairly non at all. While apply and also will always return the object used. And the counterpart of let is also and apply is run.

### Second bonus

lets say you want to check if an object is null before using it, then set its properties that are not in the constructor.

```
var mObject: MObject = mObjectUndecided?.also {
    // Do Something
}
```

But, what if mObjectUndecided is null?

```
val mObjectUndecided: MObject? = null
var mObject: MObject = mObjectUndecided?.apply{
    // Do Something
} ?: run {
    MObject().also {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

But, what if you need to call a function / variable that is the same as a mathod / property of the object?

```
val mObjectUndecided: MObject? = null
var mObject: MObject = mObjectUndecided?.let{
    // Do Something
    it // return it if its not null
} ?: run {
    MObject().also {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

But, what if MObject is constructed like this:

```
class MObject {
    var name: String? = null
    var mObjectNext: MObject? = null
}
```

Then, you will have to nest it(run, let, apply, also). But, somewhere within the nest, you want to call an object from the higher heirarchy?

```
var mObject: MObject = mObjectUndecided?.let{ mObject1 ->
    // Do Something
    mObject1.mObjectNext?.let { mObject2 ->
        // Do Something
        mObject2.mObjectNext?.let { mObject3 ->
            // Do Something
        }
        // Do Something
    }
    // Do Something
    it // return it if its not null
} ?: run {
    MObject().also {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

***P.P.S. there is another one called with, it doesn't matter enough for this context as i talked about the extension functions here, but it's something worth reading.***